# How to get the object and display in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, lit-element

I would like to know how to iterate over object array in javascript.

I have an array `sample` in which property `options` should be displayed in lit-HTML for every object

```
var sample = [{
  "trans": [{
    "id": "trans",
    "fee": 20,
    "options": ["credit", "debit"]
  }],
  "insta": [{
    "id": "insta",
    "fee": 30,
    "options": ["bank", "credit"]
  }]
}]

render(){
  sample.map((r)=>{
   <select>
     r.options.map((e)=>
      return html`

          <option>${e.options}</option>
     `
     )
   </select>
  }
}
```

Comment: What templating framework is that? Please add the tag for it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for reply, lit-element, I have added tag

Answer (score 0):

`e` is already the value of the `options` array element, you don't need to use `e.options`. So it should just be

```
<option>${e}</option>
```

You also need to loop over `r.trans.options` and `r.insta.options`.

```
render(){
  sample.map((r)=>{
   <select>
     r.trans.options.map((e)=>
      return html`

          <option>${e}</option>
     `
     )
   </select>
   <select>
     r.insta.options.map((e)=>
      return html`

          <option>${e}</option>
     `
     )
   </select>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, since i have two different array object `trans` and `insta`, my question still how to use map and dsiplay options

Comment: I didn't see that extra level of nesting. Can you show what you expect the final result to look like in plain HTML? Are they always the same keys `trans` and `insta`, or is that dynamic?

Comment: same keys `trans` and `insta` always, expected result is, for each object array, should populate the respective  `options` in select tag

Comment: But the options are the same in both `trans` and `insta`. Do you want a separate `<select>` for each key?

Comment: options are not same, please check `sample`, for `trans`, select tag should have two options `"credit", "debit"` and for `insta`, select tag should have two options `"bank", "credit"`,` Yes for each object, I need to have seperate <select> for each key`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is something like this (you are missing the return in the render function):

```
var sample=[{
  "trans":[{
   "id": "trans",
   "fee": 20,
  "options": ["credit", "debit"]
 }],
  "insta":[{
   "id": "insta",
   "fee": 30,
   "options":["bank", "credit"]
}]
}]

render(){
   return sample.map((r)=>{
   <select>
     r.options.map((e)=>
      return html`

          <option>${e.options}</option>
     `
     )
   </select>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are applying `Array.map` to `r.options`, so each element is already a single option, so you need to simply invoke

```
r.options.map( e => html`<option>${e}</option>`)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I have a sample obj with two different object array `trans` and `insta` stil can use map??

Comment: yes, you can use `obj.trans.map()` and `obj.insta.map()` and to enter into the `options` of each one,  `obj.trans.options.map()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
 



// Create a map to store the key-value pairs.
const map = new Map();
for (const key in sample) {
  map.set(key, json[key]);
}

// Iterate over the map and display the key and value of each entry in HTML.
for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  // Create an HTML element to display the key and value.
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.textContent = `Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`;

  // Append the element to the DOM.
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Also if you wanted to do in angular you can use the KeyValue pipe. check documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with explanation as to why this solves the issue